# Left join not working like expected

Tags: mysql, join

I need to do a table join to find missing translations in a translation system.

Let's say we have the following simplified table (`id` is the identifier of the string, the actual translation is not included in the example for simplicity's sake):

```
+------+-------+
| lang | id    |
+------+-------+
| en   | hello |
| en   | world |
| fr   | hello |
| de   | world |
+------+-------+
```

My initial thought was to do a simple `left join`:

```
select a.*, b.* from trans a left join trans b using (id) where a.lang = 'en';
```

I *thought* I would get this (so I could add `where b.id is null` to find the missing translation):

```
+------+-------+------+-------+
| lang | id    | lang | id    |
+------+-------+------+-------+
| en   | hello | en   | hello |
| en   | world | en   | world |
| en   | hello | fr   | hello |
| en   | world | NULL | NULL  |
| en   | hello | NULL | NULL  |
| en   | world | de   | NULL  |
+------+-------+------+-------+
```

What I *actually* get is this:

```
+------+-------+------+-------+
| lang | id    | lang | id    |
+------+-------+------+-------+
| en   | hello | en   | hello |
| en   | world | en   | world |
| en   | hello | fr   | hello |
| en   | world | de   | world |
+------+-------+------+-------+
```

What mistake have I made in my way of thinking, and what is the correct query to get the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

If you run the statement without the `where` clause you'll see why:

```
lang | id    | lang | id   
-----+-------+------+------
en   | hello | en   | hello
en   | hello | fr   | hello
fr   | hello | en   | hello
fr   | hello | fr   | hello
en   | world | en   | world
en   | world | de   | world
de   | world | en   | world
de   | world | de   | world
```

The join on the "id" column works like this:

Take the first `hello` from the table and look for all rows that contain `hello` - that yield two rows for the first hello. The same happens with the second hello, so you wind up with 2x2 rows for the join on hello. And the same for `world`

The outer join does not play any role, because there *is* a match for each id (actually: *two* matches).

You can never get your first (intended) result because that implies that all rows in the "a" table have lang='en' (which is of course not true).

To get the missing translations you need to first create the combination of all languages and ids:

```
select distinct a.id, b.lang
from trans a
  cross join trans b;
```

Now you need to find all rows that are not in that result:

```
select *
from ( 
  select distinct a.id, b.lang
  from trans a
    cross join trans b
) ac
where not exists (select 1
                  from trans mt
                  where mt.id = ac.id 
                    and mt.lang = ac.lang);
```

You can achieve this with an outer join as well. I simply prefer the `not exists` because it documents more clearly the intention (and because I hardly ever work with MySQL which is known to perform poorly with sub-queries like that)

```
select ac.*
from ( 
  select distinct a.id, b.lang
  from trans a
    cross join trans b
) ac
  left join trans mt on mt.id = ac.id and mt.lang = ac.lang
where mt.id is null;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9804d/6

**Edit**

after testing the peformance with larger tables, it seems that Sean's version of the cross join is much more efficient than mine.

So this statement should be faster than the ones above:

```
select at.*
from (
    select lang_code, label_code
    from (
        SELECT distinct lang_code 
        FROM translations
    ) as translang
      cross join (
         SELECT distinct label_code 
         FROM translations
      ) as transid
) at
  left join translations mt 
         on mt.lang_code = at.lang_code
        and mt.label_code = at.label_code
where mt.lang_code is null;
```

**Edit 2**

And another version to be tested ([SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a3e/16)):

```
SELECT a.lang, a.id,
       l.lang AS blang
FROM trans a 
  CROSS JOIN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT lang
      FROM trans
    ) l
  LEFT JOIN trans b 
    ON  b.id = a.id
    AND b.lang = l.lang 
WHERE a.lang = 'en'
  AND b.id IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Actually, when I tried the query on my translations it took 13 seconds even with just some thousand rows. And I need to add extra logic to make it work for my purpose. I think I'm ending up with comparing English to one language at a time, doing iteration programmatically. Gives for more readable, simple and speedy code.

Comment: @forthrin: yes, that's the downside of the cross join. You might try sean's version of the cross join. That seems to be faster than mine

Comment: I added one more version. Cross joins with large tables are not exactly easy to be optimized.

Comment: @ypercube: thanks, nice one as well. That assumes that all ids for english are present (i.e. english is the "reference"), right? It won't catch ids that are translated to one language but not to english.

Comment: Yes. I suppose that separate tables, one with words (ids) and one with languages would help even more with such requirements and simplify the queries.

Answer (score 2):

This query should show you what combinations of languages that are missing:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select lang, id from 
        (SELECT distinct lang FROM trans) as translang,
        (SELECT distinct id FROM trans) as transid
) alltrans 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM trans t
    WHERE t.id = alltrans.id and t.lang = alltrans.lang
)
```

Comment: Very interesting, I wouldn't have thought that, but your "disctinct cross join" is **much** more efficient than the approach I took.